# Finding URL's Within a string and replacing

Tags: c#, replace

I am trying to figure out how to look through a string which for now is called `body` and it is set equal to the length of a text box, which can be any length between `0 - 1028` characters and replace any URLs.

The URLs could start with either of the following `https`, `http`, `www.` ignoring case and would end in `.com`

The URLs ofc have no fixed length can anyone help me with this please

Edit: I haven't got much so far all I really have tried is this, with a for loop for each item in URLS, But I am not sure if this would work, or how to have the word.startsWith accept any of the www., http etc not just the specified one

```
var text1 = body;
var URLS = text1.Split(new[] { ' ' })
.Where(word => word.StartsWith("www.")) 

body = Regex.Replace(body, URLS[i], "<URL QUARANTINED>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string word2 = "";
            Regex linkParser = new Regex(@"\b(?:https?://|www\.)\S+\b", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            string bodyString = body;
            foreach (Match m in linkParser.Matches(bodyString))
            body = Regex.Replace(bodyString, m, "URL QUARANTINED");
```

and the error I am getting is Error 2   Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match' to 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchEvaluator'

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: provide sample input and output, and what you've tried.

Comment: How certain are you that the urls will always end in .com? What about all the other domains (.net, .org, .biz, .pl, .se, .com.au, .com.na)

Comment: I edited the post to show the idea that I had but not sure how to implement it properly, @BerndLinde I am not sure, but I thought adding the other domains would be very complicated so I thought .com to start with

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# regex pattern to extract urls from given string - not full html urls but bare links as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576686/c-sharp-regex-pattern-to-extract-urls-from-given-string-not-full-html-urls-but)

Comment: @BerndLinde Thanks that link was very helpful, I googled how to replace URLS and got stuff but not that, thanks for your help

Comment: @BerndLinde However I do have one error in the code that I have edited into the post, If you could help with that