# Regex to find a valid URL in a email body regardless of newlines dividing it, and it need to contains '?' character

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex to find a valid URl in a email body, but only if exists a '?' in the match.

ex:

- www.example.com.br/area?key=235fksf&rec=fsjgsg (OK)
- www.example.com.br/area?key=235fksf (OK)
- www.example.com.br/area (Not OK)

Thanks

Edit: I discovered some emails that are dividing the URL with a new line "\r\n".

PS: I'm using the site https://regex101.com/ to make some tests, but it's not working like I discribed.

Edit:

### Final Solution

To resolve the possible newline, I used the Hector's answer, and just modified to do what I needed.

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(body, @"(http(s)?:\/\/)?([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(\/[\w-;,.\/?%&=]*[\r\n]*[\w-;,.\/?%&=]*)?");
var url = string.Empty;

foreach(Match match in matches)
{
    if(match.Value.Contains('?'))
    {
        var matchSplit = match.Value.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());

        foreach(var matchUnit in matchSplit)
        {
            //Is a valid piece?
            if (matchUnit.Any(x => @"/?&=".Contains(x)))
                url += matchUnit;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it *have* to be regex? e.g., could you use Uri.TryCreate instead?

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to do it with regex, because this Url will be mixed in a email body.

Comment: Ah ok, so you're not looking to see if the WHOLE string is one big URI, you want to know if a big block of text contains such a URI (or multiple I assume). Got it.

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576686

Comment: @aquinas, thank you, it give'me ideas =)

Comment: Well @Alkaize, check the final of my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Components of a URI

```
foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
  \_/   \______________/\_________/\__________/ \__/
   |           |             |           |        |
scheme     authority       path        query   fragment
```

## Scheme

The scheme of a URL is the first item, such as http, which indicates that this URI uses the hyper-text transport protocol. Examples of other schemes are:

[image]

## Authority

In a URL the authority is also called the domain and may include a port number at the end separated by a colon.

In the following example, the authority is www.cambiaresearch.com
*

**http://www.cambiaresearch.com**

In the following example, the authority is www.cambiaresearch.com:81

**https://www.cambiaresearch.com:81**

In the following example, the authority is info@cambiaresearch.com

**mailto:info@cambiaresearch.com**

## Path

The path component of the URL specifies the specific file (or page) at a particular domain. The path is terminated by the end of the URL, a question mark (?) which signifies the beginning of the query string or the number sign (#) which signifies the beginning of the fragment.

The path of the following URL is "/default.htm"

**http://www.cambiaresearch.com/default.htm**

The path of the following URL is "/snippets/csharp/regex/uri_regex.aspx"

**http://www.cambiaresearch.com/snippets/csharp/regex/uri_regex.aspx**

## Query

The query part of the URL is a way to send some information to the path or webpage that will handle the web request. The query begins with a question mark (?) and is terminated by the end of the URL or a number sign (#) which signifies the beginning of the fragment.

The query of the following URL is "?id=241"

**http://www.cambiaresearch.com/default.htm?id=241**

The query of the following URL is "?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rls=GGLC,GGLC: 1969-53,GGLC:en&q=uri+query"

**http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rls=GGLC,GGLC:1969-53,GGLC:en&q=uri+query**

## Fragment

In a URL the fragment is used to specify a location within the current page. This is often used in a FAQ with a list of links at the top of the page linking to longer descriptions farther down in the page.

The fragment of the following URL is "contact"

**http://www.cambiaresearch.com/default.htm#contact**

The fragment of the following URL is "scheme"

**http://www.cambiaresearch.com/snippets/csharp/regex/uri_regex.aspx#scheme**

---

## Example: Regular Expressions for Parsing URIs and URLs

Simple way using `[?]` regex pattern:

```
public bool RegexUrlWithQuestionChar(string url)
{
    string pattern = @"(http(s)?://)?([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ;,./?%&=]*)?"; //Url pattern

     var regex = new Regex(pattern);
     var math = regex.Match(url);

     return new Regex("[?]").IsMatch(math.Value); //Find ?
}
```

---

```
if(RegexUrlWithQuestionChar("www.example.com.br/area?key=235fksf&rec=fsjgsg"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Found"); // This show
}
else
{
   MessageBox.Show("Not found");
}
```

---

```
if(RegexUrlWithQuestionChar("www.example.com.br/area"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Found");
}
else
{
   MessageBox.Show("Not found"); // This show
}
```

**Credits:**

[urlregex.com](http://urlregex.com)

[parsing-urls-with-regular-expressions-and-the-regex-object](https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/46/parsing-urls-with-regular-expressions-and-the-regex-object)

[www.dotnetperls.com/regex](https://www.dotnetperls.com/regex)

Comment: But this will match ANY string with a question mark, not just URLs

Comment: @aquinas Well, thanks for upvote, but even this answer has not solved the problem of the OP, I must reform it.

Comment: It was my fault for make an incomplete question, sorry

Comment: @Akaize No problem bro

Comment: @aquinas Check my answer now